# Convert Text from excel to html text

Tags: html, excel, text

I have an excel file with 450 rows of plain text,including spaces, paragraphs, bold text and bullets. This plain text must be converted to html text. Is there a way to have that done for all 450 rows… I just cant figure out a method or tool for this job. Thanks

Tried copy pasting into html editor but this is impossible to do 450 times…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is images tutorial, you must first save as and save as web page

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyout.png)[image: Done]

Comment: That creates a html file. What i need is the text from one cell being converted in html text in the other cell.  So plain text to html text with html elements

Comment: But you want excel text to html or?

Comment: You mean only text on website?

Comment: I have product descriptions in text in one excel cell. I want that same text converted into another cell with html elements like <b> <strong> etc etc to make the text more attractive

Comment: I think you cant do this, but i cant really help you more, i wish you found the answer, but i really dont know how this do.